# Error ora-01427 while executing request UPDATE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables, `ISSUENCE` and `SKLAD`, I need to make a query that will subtract the number of issued items from the total quantity in the warehouse, but the query I wrote gives an error ora-01427.

**My request:**

```
UPDATE sklad 
SET item_quantity = item_quantity - (SELECT issue_quantity FROM issuence) 
WHERE item_id = (SELECT sklad_item_id from issuence);
```

I also tried using the following query, but it deletes the quantity of the selected item from the `SKLAD` table:

```
UPDATE sklad
SET item_quantity = item_quantity - (
  SELECT issue_quantity
  FROM issuence
  WHERE issuence.sklad_item_id = sklad.item_id
)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM issuence
  WHERE issuence.sklad_item_id = sklad.item_id
);
```

The table structure looks like this:

**ISSUENCE:**

[image]

**SKLAD:**

[image]

Comment: What does ora-01427 mean?

Comment: Your first query has no correlation - `(SELECT issue_quantity FROM issuence)` will return the same number of rows for every item in the table you're updating, and that number of rows is greater than 1 - which is what the error (ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row) is telling you. For the second one, "remove the number of items for a given id" - isn't that what you want? Or do you maybe just need to exclude the rows with `issue_quantity` is null?

Comment: Don't store values calculated from other tables, your data will soon become inconsistent. At least use triggers to ensure consistency, or create a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problem with your second query

**First** when the subquery returns `null` in the column `issue_quantity` the new calculated value `item_quantity - null` is `null`. This is what you observe as *simply remove the number*.

The **second** problem remains if the subquery returns more than one row for the given `sklad_item_id`, you will be confronted with the error `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`.

To address the first issue add a filter in the `EXISTS` subquery `and  issuence.issue_quantity is not null` which will eliminate such cases from the update .

For the second problem you may calculate the `sum(issue_quantity)` in the subquery.

So the fixed query would be

```
UPDATE sklad
SET item_quantity = item_quantity - (
  SELECT sum(issue_quantity)
  FROM issuence
  WHERE issuence.sklad_item_id = sklad.item_id
)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM issuence
  WHERE issuence.sklad_item_id = sklad.item_id and  issuence.issue_quantity is not null
);
```